# Auto adjust parents height (flex element) according to children sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Below (image) is what I am trying to achieve:**

[image]

**The color1-item elements are dynamic** and can go up to 50 but can also go below 5 items so at this point, setting height in px is not an option.

I am trying to make it so that the parent's height would adjust to the childrens' size. In my attempt, the color1-item elements are overflowing to the div below it - which is not desirable. See below snippet for my attempt:

```css
.color-1-window,
.color-2-window {
  min-height: 25%;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  z-index: 50;
}

.color-window-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 65px;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-window-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.color-window-header-title {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: gibsonsemibold;
}

.color-window-header-closer {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: gibsonsemibold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.color-window-footer {
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.btn-apply.standard-btn {
  background-color: #7fc241;
  color: white;
  width: 127px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: gibsonsemibold;
  font-weight: unset;
  height: 33px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.color1-item {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 13px;
}

.color-window-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-1-window" style="">
  <div class="color-window-header">
    <div class="color-window-header-title">
      Select Color 1
    </div>
    <div class="color-window-header-closer">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-window-items">
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-window-footer">
    <div class="btn-apply standard-btn">Apply</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have absolute positionin on the footer-element and it is the one causing your problem, just remove it and you are done.

```css
.color-1-window,
.color-2-window {
  min-height: 25%;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  z-index: 50;
}

.color-window-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 65px;
  align-items: center;
}

.color-window-header-title {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: gibsonsemibold;
}

.color-window-header-closer {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: gibsonsemibold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.color-window-footer {
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.btn-apply.standard-btn {
  background-color: #7fc241;
  color: white;
  width: 127px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: gibsonsemibold;
  font-weight: unset;
  height: 33px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.color1-item {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 13px;
}

.color-window-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-1-window" style="">
  <div class="color-window-header">
    <div class="color-window-header-title">
      Select Color 1
    </div>
    <div class="color-window-header-closer">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-window-items">
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
    <div class="color1-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="color-window-footer">
    <div class="btn-apply standard-btn">Apply</div>
  </div>
</div>
```